# Who is the other voice talking to Quinn at the end?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution, the-missing-link

At the end of the Deus Ex: Human Revolution DLC, The Missing Link, who is supposed to be the voice that was talking to Quinn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [Janus](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Janus).

See [here](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/The_Missing_Link).

Comment: never heard of this guy,  I guess I should've read the book :P